# How can I cancel my asyncio Task before the unit test ends?

Tags: python, pytest, python-asyncio

I'm attempting to unit test an asynchronous socket server and using `pytest-asyncio` to make pytest compatible with the async code base. The server, once started, is always up to send a reply via a while loop, and probably spends most of its time awaiting an incoming message in `client_loop()`. The problem is there's no way to cancel this task before the unit test framework terminates the event loop and this warning gets issued:

> Task was destroyed but it is pending!
>
> task: < Task pending coro=< Server.new_client() done, defined at /[...path...]/server.py:16> wait_for=< Future pending cb=[< TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x106d7cbe8>()]>>

The only task it appears I have access to is the task created by `asyncio.create_task()`, which seems to not be the same task. That task looks like this:

> task: < Task pending coro=< start_server() running at
>   /usr/local/Cellar/python/[...different path...]/streams.py:86>>

So calling `task.cancel(); await task.wait_cancelled()` on this task is having no effect.

How can this unit test be written to cleanly start and start the server for each test and not cut off tasks which may still be running?

Here's the example:

test_server.py

```
import pytest
import asyncio

@pytest.fixture
async def server(event_loop):
    from server import Server
    the_server = Server()
    await the_server.start()
    yield the_server
    the_server.stop()

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_connect(server):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('0.0.0.0', 8888, loop = loop)
    writer.write(b'something')
    await reader.read(100)
    writer.write(b'something else')
    await reader.read(100)
    assert 1
```

server.py

```
import asyncio

class Server():
    async def start(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        coro = asyncio.start_server(self.new_client, '0.0.0.0', 8888, loop = loop)
        task = loop.create_task(coro)
        print('\n')
        print(task)
        self.server = await task

    def stop(self):
        self.server.close()

    async def new_client(self, reader, writer):
        await self.client_loop(reader, writer)

    async def client_loop(self, reader, writer):
        while True:
            await reader.read(100)
            writer.write(b'reply')
```

If you want to run this example just run `pip3 install pytest-asyncio` and pytest can pick up this plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to `await self.server.wait_closed()` after calling `self.server.close()`.

Your fixture should thus look like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
async def server(event_loop):
    from server import Server
    the_server = Server()
    await the_server.start()
    yield the_server
    await the_server.stop()
```

And the `stop` method of your `Server` should look like this:

```
    async def stop(self):
        self.server.close()
        await self.server.wait_closed()
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.Server.wait_closed) for details.

Comment: Thank you for answering. wait_closed is an important step not present in my code, but this was still not solving the main issue of open connections terminating after the unit test finished.

Answer (score 1):

The `asyncio.Server.stop()` method does not completely stop the server. It merely stops accepting new connections. Any connections created before close will continue to execute until finished.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.Server.close) *(emphasis mine)*:

> Stop serving: close listening sockets and set the sockets attribute to None.
>
> **The sockets that represent existing incoming client connections are left open.**
>
> The server is closed asynchronously, use the wait_closed() coroutine to wait until the server is closed.

In this example, all connections are sent to the infinite `client_loop` method.

A better solution is to create a collection of Tasks in `new_client()` responsible for executing `client_loop()` logic instead of awaiting the method directly. With this approach, all open Tasks can be terminated cleanly in the `stop()` method.